# how to carve out a value in html code [Instagram] using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, numbers, instagram

I'd like to carve out follower numbers using python selenium. For example, how can I carve out number below "108,381" from the html below? Please help

```
<a class="-nal3 " href="/accounts/login/?next=%2Fj_wontagii%2Ffollowers%2F&amp;source=followed_by_list">팔로워 <span class="g47SY " title="108,381">108천</span></a>

<span class="g47SY " title="108,381">108천</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options.You have to take the `title` attribute to get the value.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("g47SY ").get_attribute("title")
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.g47SY ").get_attribute("title")
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='g47SY ']").get_attribute("title")
```

Comment: I've tried as you navigated through. But, I received the message ['list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute']

Comment: I believed you have typed find_elements instead of find_element that’s why it is giving that error.Because find_elements returns list.please check your code.